# Clickhouse server can't connect to Zookeeper

Tags: azure, apache-zookeeper, database-replication, clickhouse

I am running Clickhouse server on a Azure VM and trying to create a table using ReplicatedMergeTree engine (following this guide: https://medium.com/@merticariug/distributed-clickhouse-configuration-d412c211687c).
I have zookeeper running on another Azure VM in the same subnet.

```
CREATE TABLE shard.test
(
   id Int64,
   event_time DateTime
)
Engine=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/shard1/test', 'replica_1')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(event_time)
ORDER BY id;
```

When I run the above command to create a replicated table, I get this error on my clickhouse-client:

```
Code: 225. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Can't create replicated table without ZooKeeper. (NO_ZOOKEEPER)
```

I have uncommented the zoopkeeper portion of /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml and also added a separate xml file for zookeeper in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/

Here is the content of /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/zookeeper.xml:

```
<clickhouse>
    <zookeeper>
        <node>
            <host>public_IP</host>
            <port>2181</port>
        </node>
    </zookeeper>
</clickhouse>
```

Am I missing some config changes?

Answer (score 0):

probably the problem is network restrictions, firewall, ...

this should work from CH server

```
 echo stat | nc public_IP 2181
```

Comment: Yep this works. I'm able to see zookeeper stats.
Any other way to check the network restrictions?

Comment: @Heyb check 'SELECT * FROM system.zookeeper WHERE path='/''

Comment: I get this error: Code: 60. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Table system.zookeeper doesn't exist. (UNKNOWN_TABLE)

Comment: @Slach could you please help me out here?

Comment: Are you sure you have <zookeeper> section in your /var/lib/clickhouse/preprocessed_configs/config.xml ?

maybe you need replace <clickhouse> to <yandex>
in your configuration in config.d file

Comment: Yep replacing <clickhouse> with <yandex> and restarting clickhouse-server worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In zookeeper.xml, replace `<clickhouse>` and `</clickhouse>` with `<yandex>` and `</yandex>` respectively. Then restart the clickhouse-server using `sudo service clickhouse-server restart`.

Comment: it means that you use obsolete version of CH

Comment: I'm using CH version 22.2.2.1. Is that obsolete?

Comment: 22.2 supports `<clickhouse>` tags

Comment: `yandex` tags are obsolete after 21.10